# How to get Sqoop Server Running URL and Port in Horton Sandbox

Tags: java, mapreduce, sqoop, hortonworks-data-platform, sqoop2

I am using sqoop client. And don't know by which URL I have to initialize the SqoopClient Object. I am running horton Sandbox which is preconfigured with everything. I dont know it is having sqoop server running or not. And If it is running then I dnt know the port. And If it is not running how can I run it in Sandbox.

I am reading tutorial given at this page: http://devslogics.blogspot.in/2013/09/sqoop-java-client.html

This two lines is the focus to initialize with url.

```
  String url = "http://192.168.56.102:12000/sqoop/"; 
  SqoopClient client = new SqoopClient(url);
```

Here is my complete code -

```
//Here I am using a table Persons, with columns PersonID and LastName
import org.apache.sqoop.client.SqoopClient;
import org.apache.sqoop.model.MConnection;
import org.apache.sqoop.model.MConnectionForms;
import org.apache.sqoop.model.MJob;
import org.apache.sqoop.model.MJobForms;
import org.apache.sqoop.model.MSubmission;
import org.apache.sqoop.validation.Status;

/**
 * @author  devan
 * @date 19-Sep-2013
 * @mail msdevanms@gmail.com
 */

public class SqoopImport {
 public static void main(String[] args) {


  String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3316/dw_db";
  String username = "openmrs";
  String password = "ePM2zeKZOzrL";
  String schemaName = "dw_db";
  String tableName = "dw_table";
  String columns = "locale,name"; //comma seperated column names
  String partitionColumn = "locale";
  String outputDirectory = "/output/Persons";
  String url = "http://192.168.56.102:12000/sqoop/";


  SqoopClient client = new SqoopClient(url);
  //client.setServerUrl(newUrl);
  //Dummy connection object
  MConnection newCon = client.newConnection(1);

  //Get connection and framework forms. Set name for connection
  MConnectionForms conForms = newCon.getConnectorPart();
  MConnectionForms frameworkForms = newCon.getFrameworkPart();
  newCon.setName("MyConnection");

  //Set connection forms values
  conForms.getStringInput("connection.connectionString").setValue(connectionString);
  conForms.getStringInput("connection.jdbcDriver").setValue("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  conForms.getStringInput("connection.username").setValue(username);
  conForms.getStringInput("connection.password").setValue(password);

  frameworkForms.getIntegerInput("security.maxConnections").setValue(0);

  Status status  = client.createConnection(newCon);
  if(status.canProceed()) {
   System.out.println("Created. New Connection ID : " +newCon.getPersistenceId());
  } else {
   System.out.println("Check for status and forms error ");
  }

  //Creating dummy job object
  MJob newjob = client.newJob(newCon.getPersistenceId(), org.apache.sqoop.model.MJob.Type.IMPORT);
  MJobForms connectorForm = newjob.getConnectorPart();
  MJobForms frameworkForm = newjob.getFrameworkPart();

  newjob.setName("ImportJob");
  //Database configuration
  connectorForm.getStringInput("table.schemaName").setValue(schemaName);
  //Input either table name or sql
  connectorForm.getStringInput("table.tableName").setValue(tableName);
  //connectorForm.getStringInput("table.sql").setValue("select id,name from table where ${CONDITIONS}");


  connectorForm.getStringInput("table.columns").setValue(columns);
  connectorForm.getStringInput("table.partitionColumn").setValue(partitionColumn);

  //Set boundary value only if required
  //connectorForm.getStringInput("table.boundaryQuery").setValue("");

  //Output configurations
  frameworkForm.getEnumInput("output.storageType").setValue("HDFS");
  frameworkForm.getEnumInput("output.outputFormat").setValue("TEXT_FILE");//Other option: SEQUENCE_FILE / TEXT_FILE
  frameworkForm.getStringInput("output.outputDirectory").setValue(outputDirectory);
  //Job resources
  frameworkForm.getIntegerInput("throttling.extractors").setValue(1);
  frameworkForm.getIntegerInput("throttling.loaders").setValue(1);

  status = client.createJob(newjob);
  if(status.canProceed()) {
   System.out.println("New Job ID: "+ newjob.getPersistenceId());
  } else {
   System.out.println("Check for status and forms error ");
  }
  //Now Submit the Job
  MSubmission submission = client.startSubmission(newjob.getPersistenceId());
  System.out.println("Status : " + submission.getStatus());

 }


}
```

Comment: i have similar issue. i know sqoop is running in my node. 
i'm able to perform import and export via command line util. 
however when i try to do the same via Sqoop Java Client API i have trouble in  creating new connection. 
MConnection newCon = new SqoopClient("http://sanbox.hortonworks.com:12000/sqopp").newConnection(1);

Comment: i'm getting this exception during execution. 
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
 at org.apache.sqoop.client.request.Request$ServerExceptionFilter.handle(Request.java:85)
 ..at org.apache.sqoop.client.request.Request.get(Request.java:62)
 ..at org.apache.sqoop.client.SqoopClient.retrieveConnector(SqoopClient.java:140)
 ...getConnector(SqoopClient.java:130) ~[sqoop-client-1.99.2.jar:1.99.2]
 ...newConnection(SqoopClient.java:225) ~[sqoop-client-1.99.2.jar:1.99.2]

Answer (score 0):

For checking list of services running on any linux machine,please try the following one:

**netstat -tulpn**

This will list all the services.

To get a particular service or port,you can grep port name with this command.

**For example:netstat -tulpn | grep 8080**

To list all running services

**netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN**

Hope,this will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Running in server mode option is not available for Sqoop1. It is only available for Sqoop2. Make sure that you are using Sqoop2.

[See this link to know how start the sqoop server](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_14_4.html)